# Can I add unallocated space to an existing partition?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

My machine is windows 7 ultimate 32-bit with the HDD like this (from left to right);

> C: / unallocated space (about 40GB) / D: / E:

Now I want to add this unallocated space into my E: drive without repartitioning the C or D drives. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: (In reply to your comment under Brad Patton's answer:) Step 4 of my answer explains how to *move* the *D* drive.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in Windows.

1) Open Control Panel and go to System and Security.

2) Select Create and format hard disk partitions (you will need admin access).

[image: Control Panel]

3) In the Disk Management Console select the partition you want to increase in size and right click to open a pop-up menu.

4) Select 'Extend Volume...' and enter the amount you want to increase the partition by.

[image: Disk MGMT]

Comment: I was just typing this answer in. You beat me to it! +1

Comment: Thank you for all you guys. The trivial extend and shrink is simple for many users. But you didn't noticed that unallocated space is not next to E: drive.

Comment: @flyhipy just tested this with a blank disk and disk mgmt will extend the e: drive into the unallocated space with the caveat that it will convert the disk to a dynamic disk.

Comment: Additionally the free version of Partition Wizard (http://www.partitionwizard.com/) could be used with the same steps Dennis outlines.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do 1 of 2 things. Either render it as another partition or use gparted to expand your partition to use that space.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, you have to move the *D* drive to the beginning of the unallocated space, then resize the *E* drive. Many third-party partition managers are able to perform both tasks.

You could, e.g., download the [Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (or [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php)) LiveCD, [burn it to a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows) or create a [bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and do the following:

1. Boot from your Live CD and click **Try Ubuntu** when it asks whether to try or install it.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>, type *gparted* and click **GParted Partition Editor**.
3. Right-click your *D* and *E* drive and select **Unmount** if it's available.
4. Right-click your *D* drive, select **Resize/Move**, place the mouse cursor over the slider, drag the partition all to the left and confirm.

   Now, you have

   > C: / D: / unallocated space / E:
5. Right-click your *E* drive, select **Resize/Move**, place the mouse cursor over left arrow of the slider, extend the partition all to the left and confirm.
6. Click the green checkmark labeled **Apply All Operations**.

Whenever you resize or move a partition, there's a certain risk of data loss (failing HDD, power outage, etc.). Make sure you backup your most important files.

Answer (score 0):

for changing the size, move , reallocate your hard disk partition without delete any partition simply you can use easeus partition master the is free from personal use. external info from [here](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm), and download link from [here](http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm).

Comment: Thank you for all you guys. The trivial extend and shrink is simple for many users. But you didn't noticed that unallocated space is not next to E: drive.

Comment: no problem anyway!!!! you can move D nearby c with that application then add unallocated space to E