# Windows 7 Extend Main Partition Not allowed

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

UPDATE

- I have changed this SSD to "dynamic disk" https://superuser.com/a/1080796/1074900
- merged the 70 GB Other NTFS partition to the 10 GB Unallocated space than restarted the machine than It says the following at boot: `BOOTINGMR is  missing press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart`
- In the bios it does not offer my operation system's SSD as boot option (1st 2nd or 3rd) but it sees it in other settings. If  I directly click on it to boot from it it just gives me the previous ERROR.
- I have created a bootable windows 7 USB to do [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2622803/bootmgr-is-missing-press-ctrl-alt-del-to-restart-error-when-you-start). But It does not want to boot from that from the bios (I used Boot Camp Assistant for the bootable pendrive)

BASE SITUATION

- Windows 7 Professional
- I have a min SSD that is separated to 4 areas

  - 100 MB area that was created by windows at installation
  - 100 GB Main System Partition NTFS
  - 70 GB Other Partition NTFS
  - 10 GB Unallocated partition
- I want to add the Unallocated partition to the Main partition but in "Computer Managment" it grays out that option when I click on the main drive
- I have tried with EaseUS but that also cant resize or extend the main partion. When I try to resize it it says there is 0 unallocated partition while on the bar chart there is clearly unallocated space/partition

TRIED SOLUTIONS

- I don't have any other storage options so I  cant use these answers - [Can't extend C partition. How to make unallocated space "adjacent"](https://superuser.com/questions/1080603/cant-extend-c-partition-how-to-make-unallocated-space-adjacent)
- https://www.diskpart.com/articles/how-to-add-unallocated-space-to-d-drive.html
- [Can I add unallocated space to an existing partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/557847/can-i-add-unallocated-space-to-an-existing-partition)

Comment: You have to move "Other partition" to the end of the drive first.

Comment: How I  can do that (this is a SATA SSD)?

Comment: No idea, I've never had to do it.

Comment: At least I know where to search, thank you.

Comment: Is it in GPT mode?

Comment: What is GPT? It is Windows 7 professional, Desktop pc.

Comment: @sogu GPT stands for GUID partition table and it is used in UEFI systems and also different from BIOS master boot record MBR. Each UEFI partition has a GUID in the partition table and most modern EFI-based systems use it. You can check at the startup if you are using UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: If you are using gpt ssd and have it in mbr mode, then try converting it to gpt

Comment: I can not access the command prompt anymore to do changes like this  https://neosmart.net/wiki/convert-gpt-to-mbr/ because of [updated the post]